# Wordpress 3 - how are passwords stored and how do I compare to them?

Tags: php, mysql

For reasons I can't go into right now, I'm creating a form that will allow users to change their passwords for Wordpress by entering their current password and then entering the new password.

I want to do a databse lookup to see if the password they entered was the correct one already stored in the DB. However, in WP the passwords are encrypted somehow, so doing a simple SQL comparison on this column wont work. I tried using `md5()` on the password for the lookup but it doesn't seem to work either.

Here's my sql:
`SELECT ID, user_pass 
FROM wp_users 
WHERE ID = '$current_user->ID'
AND user_pass = 'md5($currentpassword)'
LIMIT 1`

You can ignore most of this, but what I need to know is how I can do a comparison against the user_pass column?

I've tested this method above and it results in 0 rows returned - with or without the `md5()`

Please help!

Much appreciated.

Michael.

Answer (score 8):

Wordpress appears to have a built in function called [wp_hash_password](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password) that will hash the given password and then you can compare it in the db.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response. I have tried using the above function in place of where I had the MD5() function, but still no joy. Hmm. Any further ideas? Do you have a script you know that works? Thanks again.

Comment: You cannot call wp_hash_password from MySQL. You must call it in PHP as per @Anthony's linked example.  If you post full code someone might be able to help you.

Comment: @Ciaran I am running this SQL in a PHP WordPress template. Just using a standard PHP query where I check the number of rows returned. I'm not executing this SQL on the database itself or anywhere outside of PHP / WordPress.